# iOS UITableView blanks after didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, didreceivememorywarning

I am at a bit of a loss here, and I'm hoping someone can point out where I've gone wrong.

My application is a Master/View application meant for iPads.

My MasterView inherits from UITableView, and works just fine as long as there's no didReceiveMemoryWarning.  I've got custom cell contents, and it all works a treat.  So far so good, and only took a couple hours to build.

However, once I get a didReceiveMemoryWarning, the self.tableView seems to behave strangely.  The numberOfSectionsInTableView and tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: methods are never called again, and when my code tried to select the first item (after the memory warning) like this:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] 
                animated:NO
                scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

it crashes with

> -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'

So what gives?  If the memory of my tableView is completely wiped during the memory warning, why wasn't it just set to nil?  Also how do I build it up again?

Answer (score 1):

Are you implementing the tableview per interface builder oder per code? When you use self i assume you use a property with retain. Check if you set this one to nil in your viewDidUnLoad and release the field pointer in your dealloc method. If not the problem lays somewhere else, but i assume you do it because its good practice.

If you've built the tableview by code and you set the property to nil in your viewDidUnload, you have to allocate it again after you received your memory warning. Places to do that would be viewDidLoad, initWith etc... View did load is mostly the better option as it gets called as soon as you go back through a Nav- or TabBarController.

If you use interface builder and your view gets loaded in your AppDelegate (for example in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method), the awakeFromNib method will never get called again unless you call it again. So DONT set instance variables to nil in that case in your viewDidUnload. You will loose the pointer to the interface builder tableview otherwise.This last part could be the reason but actually it shouldn't because IMO its not good practice.

If you tell me more about your code i can help you more specifically.

Greetings
Markus

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for writing.  I apologise, I hadn't given context: OSX 10.6.8, Xcode 4.2, project is using ARC, target is iPad 2 running iOS 5.0.0.

Comment: The problem turned out to be that the table's contents were blizted, along with the contents of an array I count on to know what to put into the table.  The array named 'docs' was 'nil'ed, so [docs count] was returning 'nil', not '0', so when I got to the selectRowAtIndexPath, it was bound to blow up as there are 'nil' rows, not '0' rows.

Comment: I feel letting a 'nil' object receive a message without crashing is a fundamental mistake in ObjectiveC, because it changes the type of the return object from an int to a nil.  If the crash had happened on the [docs count] line, I'd have known exactly where the problem is, not in another method entirely.

Comment: Once I caught this, and rebuild the table in viewDidLoad, at least I am recovering from my table being yanked out from under me when the didReceiveMemoryWarning happens.